# Dates getting modified to1970-01-01T00:00:01.659452061Z when writing it to InfluxDb using the InfluxDb php client

Tags: php, influxdb, unix-timestamp, influxdb-2, influx-line-protocol

I am using PHP Client for InfluxDB - https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-php

I am inserting points in my measurement along with current timestamp. For the timestamp, I am using as follows -

```
$time = new \DateTime();
$timezone=new\DateTimeZone('UTC');
$time->setTimestamp($unixTime)->setTimezone($timezone);
```

And then in then while inserting the point I am using -

```
->time($time->getTimestamp());
```

When I echo this variable, I get the correct timestamp, but when I am checkin values in the InfluxDB, all the dates are replaced by

```
1970-01-01T00:00:01.659452061Z
```

I even set the timezone to be UTC. I am not sure how to get the current timestamp into InfluxDB. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Default precision is nanoseconds. You need to set it to seconds, ie.

```php
$client = new InfluxDB2\Client([
    ...
    "precision" => InfluxDB2\Model\WritePrecision::S,
]);
```

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-php#time-precision

Comment: Hi @alespour, I have set the precision to NS in client. When I try to change it to S, I start getting the following error - 

"Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response: {"code":"unprocessable entity","message":"failure writing points to database: partial write: field type conflict"

Comment: @Shubhamkhetan That's strange. What if use NS precision and just convert the timestamp from seconds to nanos like `->time($time->getTimestamp() * 1000000000);`?